# How do I elongate the list to view more cards at once in Trello?

Tags: trello

When I click on the lower right hand corner of a list, it condenses it. But how do I un-condense it to view more at once?

Comment: Do you have some sort of customization working with Trello? There is no built-in list condense/collapse interface. https://trello.com/card/collapsible-lists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1170

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing on the site that lets you condense lists. I'm not sure how or why that's happening. Did you click the 'Add card' text at the bottom of the list? That may have shifted the cards up. If so, just click the 'x' or click off the text input to clear the selection and expand the card list.

If you want more cards on the screen, you can zoom out in the browser.

- To zoom out, use control + '+' (Windows) or command + '+' (Mac).
- To zoom in, use control + '-' (Windows) or command + '-' (Mac).

(That may differ per browser.)